# diff ignore white spaces or the same string on a different line

Tags: diff

I need to make diff between two files but If I have the same lines in the files on a different line, I don't want to display any output. 
Example:
File1:

```
cc aaaw
bb bbbw

aa cccw
```

File2:

```
cc aaaw

bb bbbw
aa cccw
```

diff file1 file2:

```
2d1
< bb bbbw
3a3
> bb bbbw
 -> I don't want any output
```

but If I have file1 as the one above and file2:

```
cc aaaw

bb bbbw
aa cccw
ddddddd
```

I want this output:

```
4a5
> ddddddd
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `diff -B` to ignore empty/blank lines.